# Creating a Struct from a List

Tags: elixir

I have the following list of structures in my module:

```rb
defmodule Team do
  defstruct name: nil, points: nil
end

team1 = %Team{name: "Team 1", points: "00"}
team2 = %Team{name: "Team 2", points: "50"}
team3 = %Team{name: "Team 3", points: "25"}
team4 = %Team{name: "Team 4", points: "12"}
team5 = %Team{name: "Team 5", points: "04"}
team6 = %Team{name: "Team 6", points: "32"}

teams = [team1, team2, team3, team4, team5, team6]
```

I also have the following structure:

```rb
defmodule Match do
  defstruct team1: nil, team2: nil
end
```

How can I assemble a Match list based on the Teams on this list?

For example, Match: team1, team2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it quite easily:

```
def build(list), do: do_build(list, [])

defp do_build([], result), do: result
defp do_build([a, b | rest], result), do: do_build(rest, [%Match{team1: a, team2: b} | result])
defp do_build(_, _), do: raise "Odd number of elements in list"
```

Answer (score 3):

@Hauleth has posted a correct answer with recursion but I would use `Enum.chunk_every/2` for simplicity:

```
for [a, b] <- Enum.chunk_every(teams, 2), do: %Match{team1: a, team2: b}
```